# Parametrized CTE

Tags: sql, postgresql

Let's say I have a table-function that I'm currently doing with a CTE, for example:

```
WITH info AS (
    SELECT * FROM sales WHERE website='Google'
) SELECT * FROM info JOIN other USING (id)
```

Is there a way to parametrize the CTE such that I can do something like:

```
WITH table_function_info($var1) AS (
    SELECT * FROM sales WHERE website=$var1
)
```

And then I could call it as:

```
WITH info AS 
    table_function_info('Yahoo')
SELECT * FROM info JOIN other USING (id)
```

Or what is the proper way to parametrize a table function in a postgres (CTE?) Note that I don't necessarily know the output columns, and they may potentially change (for example, if a user adds/removes a column in the `sales` table).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a function that returns a set of rows of the type `sales`, e.g.

```sql
create or replace function select_from_sales(arg text)
returns setof sales language sql as $$
    select * from sales where website = arg
$$;
```

The output format of the function will adapt to possible modifications to the table structure, test it in [Db<>fiddle.](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=5c790edcdf948491a9d65357a4ff4231) Postgres automatically creates a corresponding type for every created/altered table in a database. This allows a user to declare the return type of a function in an easy way.

Comment: awesome, one question: what does `setof` mean -- does that just mean the table returns rows of whatever the `sales` table structure is?

Comment: Yes, I supplemented the answer with a mention of this.